# Why does the following way of creating DOM elements not work with jQuery in IE7 and IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8

Sometimes, it is useful to create DOM elements as jQuery objects for use as selectors and context.

The following works in **both** IE7,IE8 and all other browsers using jQuery 1.6.2/3 - but note that `document.createElement` is used to make this work.in IE7 and IE8.

```
   jQuery('body').append('<div id="basic-render-test"> </div>');

   var new_object = {};
   new_object.wrapper = '<span id="adfasdfasdfwersadfas3rs">';
   //alert(typeof new_object.wrapper);

   if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version <= 8.0){ 
       new_object.el = document.createElement(new_object.wrapper);
   } else  {
       new_object.el = jQuery(new_object.wrapper);
   }

   new_object.render_into = "#basic-render-test";
   jQuery(new_object.render_into).append( new_object.el );
   some_html = '<DIV id="type-m" class="translate"> HELLO IE</DIV>';
   jQuery(new_object.el).html( some_html );
```

The declared DOM type is HTML 5

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide an actual valid html code for it to be created properly. In your exemple, your span tag is not closed, which result in an invalid code at evaluation in IE while other browsers tend to fix it automagically.

Replace

```
new_object.wrapper = '<span id="adfasdfasdfwersadfas3rs">';
```

With

```
new_object.wrapper = '<span id="adfasdfasdfwersadfas3rs"></span>';
```

[This exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/B66tn/3/) runs perfectly on both IE 7 and 8

Comment: this WORKS In IE8 change "<span>" to "<span/>" works just great (havent tested in IE7)

Comment: It is mentioned in jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2 : "To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag"

Answer (score 2):

In looking at the jQuery code, it takes a different code path if what you pass to the jQuery function is a simple tag like `"<span>"` vs. what you're passing.  When it's a simple tag, jQuery calls `createElement() on it, pretty much like your workaround code`.  When it's not a simple tag, jQuery calls `createDocumentFragment()` and then takes a lot more complicated path involving a temporary div, setting your HTML into the innerHTML, etc...

If you make your HTML be a simple tag and then add the id attribute to the object after it's created, it should follow the createElement code path.

To work-around this, change this:

```
new_object.wrapper = '<span id="adfasdfasdfwersadfas3rs">';
```

to this:

```
new_object.wrapper = '<span id="adfasdfasdfwersadfas3rs"></span>';
```

From [this jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be
>   well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired
>   with a closing tag.

Your HTML was not paired with a closing tag.